# nodejs run functions back to back

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm writing a small nodejs script to copy files from another folder, modify some text and minify the contents.

As per my research, there seems to be module called `async` with which functions can be called one by one. But I'm trying how to do the same without installing any modules (as a part of learning).

I'm new to this promises/async world. But I could not get it to work sequentially as expected.
Can someone please help ?

```
function updateText( textList ){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        var folders = [ 'includes/lr', 'includes/vc' ];
        var acceptedFileTypes = ['php', 'js', 'css'];
    
        folders.forEach(function(dir){
            files = walk(dir);
            files.forEach( function ( file ) {

                fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                    
                    fileType = file.split('.').pop();
                    if(!acceptedFileTypes.includes(fileType)){
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log('Editing - ' + file);

                    if (err) {
                      return console.log(err);
                    }
    
                    for(text in textList){
                        data = data.replace(new RegExp(text, 'g'), textList[text]);
                    }
    
                    fs.writeFile(file, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
                        console.log('Written file - ' + file);
                       if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
    
                });
    
            });
        });

        console.log('Resolving')
        resolve();

    });
}

function minifyJS(){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        minify('includes/vc/js/script-front.js').then(function(data){
            console.log('Minifying file - ');
            fs.writeFile('includes/vc/js/script-front.min.js', data, 'utf8', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                resolve();
             });
        });
    });

}

updateText({
    'qwerty': 'hello',
})
.then(function(r){
    minifyJS().then(function(){
        console.log('# Done');
    });
})
```

Output - things are all over the place and not in sequence, though promise is resolved only after editing the files.

Here I'm expecting, all edits to finish first, writes second and minify at the last.

```
Resolving
Editing - includes/lr/css/style.css
Editing - includes/vc/css/style.css
Editing - includes/vc/js/script-front.js
Editing - includes/vc/js/script-front.min.js
Minifying file -
Editing - includes/vc/js/script.js
Editing - includes/lr/js/script.js
Editing - includes/vc/index.php
Editing - includes/lr/index.php
Written file - includes/lr/css/style.css
Written file - includes/vc/css/style.css
Written file - includes/vc/js/script-front.js
Written file - includes/vc/js/script.js
Written file - includes/lr/js/script.js
Written file - includes/vc/js/script-front.min.js
# Done
Written file - includes/vc/index.php
Written file - includes/lr/index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there seems to be module called async with which functions can be called one by one. But I'm trying how to do the same without installing any modules (as a part of learning).

`async`/`await` does not require any module loading and is available as part of the NodeJS runtime starting with NodeJS 8.0.0

- [here is a post with some examples of how to use](http://peterforgacs.github.io/2017/05/29/How-to-use-async-await-with-Node-js-8-0-0/)

I see the use of `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile`, both of which make use of the callback function.

That callback functions will be invoked once `fs.readFile`/`fs.writeFile` completes their task.

Calls to `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` are placed on the [event-loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and are not guaranteed to complete in the order in which they were added.
To demonstrate the blocking of the event-loop, you can make use of the synchronous calls from the `fs` module

- [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)
- [fs-writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

I would suggest restructuring the code to make use of [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which will will allow the `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` to be "promisified" and then can be used with `async`/`await`.

```
const listOfFilesRead = await readFiles
await writeFiles(listOfFilesRead)
await minify
```

- `readFiles` would be a declared `async` function that makes use of `util.promisify` on `fs.readFile`, returning an array of `data` to be used in `writeFiles`
- `writeFiles` would be a declared `async` function that makes use of `util.promisify` on `fs.writeFile` to await on each write, before moving onto the next, taking in an array of `data` of files to be written
- `minify` is an async function that will minify the JS

That will give the order you are wanting of `readAll`, `writeAll`, `minify`

As it is written, it is attempting to do the following

- read a file
- write that file
- repeat for all files
- then minify

Since you are learning, the links provided should give examples of how to write callback, promise-based, and async-await of asynchronous functions.

Comment: Thanks @Manny. I was actually talking about the https://www.npmjs.com/package/async package. Anyways I replaced `readFile` and `writeFile` with their `sync` functions and it worked as expected. The functions worked async and there was no need for a promise callbacks.